# How to count number of repeated clients

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm a newbie in PBI. I'm facing a problem with creating measure as below:

[image]

My task is to fulfill the Mark column with criteria:

- **NEW:** For the clients who 1st time order
- **Repeat:** From 2nd order in later months and current order date must be 6 days larger than the last order.

It was done in excel by:

```
=IF(
    COUNTIF($B$5:B5,B5)=1,
    "NEW",
    IF(
        AND(
            COUNTIFS($B$5:B5,B5,$D$5:D5,D5)=1,
            ([@[Order date]]-LARGE(IF($B$5:B5=B5,$C$5:C5),2)>=7)
        ),
        "Repeat",
        "2nd in Month"
    )
)
```

But I don't know how to create in DAX/PQ to get expecting result as:

[image]